# Django Cannot Import Local Module During Migrations

Tags: python, django, migration

In my project i've got two custom objects, defined in a local fields.py file & blocks.py file. I import them in my models.py as such:

```
from . import fields as blockfields
from . import blocks
```

and when running migrations, the autogenerated migrations look like this:

```
import PROJECTNAME.fields
import blocks
```

and since blocks isnt in the local scope of the migrations folder, it throws an error. If i manually change it to "import PROJECTNAME.blocks as blocks" then it runs fine, but it'd be silly to have to do that every time. Any thoughts?

---

Updates:
Using Django 2.1.4, Python 3.6.7

Folder structure is thus:

```
PROJECTNAME
-fields.py
-models.py
-blocks/
--__init__.py
--*.py
-migrations/
--*.py
```

Ive variably tried having a blocks.py file which just points to the folder, but it doesn't change the import scope for the automigration.

In my blockfields, i refer to blocks also, which is how the references get baked into the migrations. The fields.py file has an extension of django's generic models.Field, while the blocks are custom types from scratch.

Comment: Can you give us more info? particularly which Python/Django version you are using and the whole directory structure of your project

Comment: @ModestLeech done!